# Has anyone ever sucessfully translated xRNA or yRNA?

Tags: synthetic-biology, translation, polymerase

I've recently been researching the subject of size-expanded nucleobases in alternative genetic sets. Many papers describe the, at least, partial success in replicating xDNA and yDNA, as well as transcribing them, as suggested [here](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3152792/).

> At the same time, studies on polymerase replication and transcription of oligonucleotide sequences reveal that chemical entities other than the typical nucleoside triphosphates can be tolerated to varying degrees.

My question is **can the cell's molecular machinery, including ribosomes and tRNA, possibly lead to translation of xRNA or yRNA? Would the translation product yield the traditional 20 amino acids? Have this ever been attempted?**

References to original papers would be appreciated. Thanks!